# in android socket: in the server only part of the array[] is received, is there a max size in socket?

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I developed clint in android, and server c#
1- when i send small string as"hello world" it sent successfully to server and the client receive the response msg also from sever

2- Now, i tried to send LARGE string (Actually it is an image representation) from 
android, the size of string msg is 23.000 bytes. **THE PROBLEMS with the large string are:**

```
1- the server c# did not receive  all the string bytes 
2- the response Msg did not received to the client
```

the code are **the same** in both experiments ONly the different in the string **size** please advice me

this is the client android JAVA only the function of connection:
        public void ConnectToServer()
    {

```
    Thread ConnectToClient = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {try {
            Log.e("MESSAGE", "HERE void run");

            // time start here
            Log.e("MESSAGE", "Start time");
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            //Connect to socket 
            Log.e("MESSAGE", "HERE socket object");
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
              Log.e("MESSAGE", String.valueOf(client_str));
                        client_str = “hellow world”; //the problem if this string is huge i cannot write the string here it is too long


            DataOutputStream output_to_server = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            output_to_server.writeBytes(client_str);
            output_to_server.flush();
               //receive ACK from (server)
                                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    Log.e("MESSAGE", "Recieve the ACK from server");
                    recievedMsg = in.readLine();

                    Log.e("MESSAGE", String.valueOf(recievedMsg));

            //Update TextView
            Message msg = null;
            msg = textview_handler_thread.obtainMessage();
            msg.obj = recievedMsg;
            textview_handler_thread.sendMessage(msg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    ConnectToClient.start();
}
```

and this is the c# server :

```
   namespace CloudLet1Code
{
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.4");

            // Initializes the Listener
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAdress, 4003);
        // Start Listeneting at the specified port
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server running - Port: 4003");
        Console.WriteLine("Local end point:" + listener.LocalEndpoint);
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections...");

        Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
        // When accepted
        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
        byte[] b = new byte[1000000];
        string rcvd_msg = null;        
        int k = s.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved...\n");

         for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
         {
              Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
             rcvd_msg += Convert.ToChar(b[i]).ToString();
         }
        Console.WriteLine("\nrcvd_msg = " + rcvd_msg);
        listener.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Automatic message sent!");

        ///send ack
        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server number 1."));
        Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
        // ack sent 
        s.Close();

    }
}
```

}
UPDATED CODE (c#) ..receiving data in chunks but still cannot extract the string:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2");

        // Initializes the Listener
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAdress, 4003);
        // Start Listeneting at the specified port
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server running - Port: 4003");
        Console.WriteLine("Local end point:" + listener.LocalEndpoint);
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections...");

        Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
        // When accepted
        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);


        MemoryStream bufferStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        //keep reading blocks from stream until there is no more data received
        //receive will block until there is data or the end of the stream has been reached
        while((count = s.Receive(buffer))!=0)
        {
            //write all received bytes into buffer stream ( which is in memory byte stream)
            bufferStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        //get the entire brte array from the stream
        byte[] entireData = bufferStream.ToArray();
        //convert the received data to string using ascii incoding 
        String ReceivingDataString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(entireData);


        Console.WriteLine("Automatic message sent!");

        ///send ack

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server number 1."));
        Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
        // ack sent 
        s.Close();


    }
```

Comment: For a package that size, you may not receive all of the bytes in a single call to receive. You may need to implement something in which the server is told how many bytes it is going to receive, then receives until that many bytes are accumulated.

Comment: so the problem in java or c# code??

Comment: please could you explain your answer .. this issue really waste my time :(

Comment: If your `send` call completes successfully, then that is likely fine. If you are not receiving all of the bytes, then you need a change on your receiving end.

Comment: How can i know if the client send the msg successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the issue to be in the line `int k = s.Receive(b);` in your C# application. This is because such a large data chunk won't necessarily arrive in 1 packet, which means that the entire body of the stream will not be available with one call to `Socket.Receive()`. You could try putting this in a loop, and keep reading all the data until there is none available (the end of the stream). Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff(v=vs.110).aspx, particular the Remarks at the bottom:

> "If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method
>   will read as much data as is available"

This is saying that if there is any available data, it will return that right away - it will not wait for the stream to end before returning all available data and loading that into your buffer (since potentially the stream is gigabytes long, and may not fit in memory). The following example shows a quick example of how you could start to implement receiving the data in chunks and buffering them into a MemoryStream.

```
Socket s = yoursocket;
MemoryStream bufferStream = new MemoryStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count;
// Keep reading blocks from the stream until there is no more data being received.
// As specified in the docs, Receive will block until there is data - or the end of the
// stream has been reached.
while((count = s.Receive(buffer)) != 0)
{
    // Write all received bytes into the buffer stream
    // (which is an in memory byte stream)
    bufferStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}

// Get the entire byte array from the stream
byte[] entireData = bufferStream.ToArray();

// Convert the received data to a string using ascii encoding
string receivedDataAsString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(entireData);
```

As a side note, since your sending images you shouldn't be using a text encoding (eg ASCII encoding), but that has nothing to do with the actual problem preventing all the data from being received in one go. I hope this gives you some insight into how you could go about solving your problem.

EDIT: Socket.Receive() will not return 0 until the remote peer has ended the stream. Sending no more data does not constitute the end of the stream. Thus, in order to cause the example loop above (`while((count = s.Receive(buffer)) != 0)` to break out, your remote peer would need to close the stream completely. (using `DataOutputStream.close()` in your case). Also, you would need to catch some of the exceptions thrown by Socket.Receive based on the different scenarios that a remote peer will appear disconnected under (eg, Timeout). If you are wanting to process data without waiting for the stream to close, you will need to use the data as it arrives - directly inside the while loop in my example. Eg:

```
while((count = s.Receive(buffer)) != 0)
    {
        // Convert the current buffer to a string (using the number of read bytes as the length of this string)
        string newText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, count);
       //Console.WriteLine($"New data received: {newText}");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..i tried to receiving data in chunks ..and by using breakpoints in c#.. we cant out of the loop i dont know.. i used smaller string and also the loop is still no end.. the updates in my code is available above in the question

Comment: Just as a side note, you can use tools such as https://packetsender.com/ to test and debug client and server tcp connections.

Comment: Another thing to understand... Socket.Receive will not return 0 (it will just block) until there is NO data left (eg, the client closed the stream completely). If you are needing to process the data in real-time (or, using parts of the data as it arrives) you out will need to process each received chunk as it is received. (Try console printing the string version of the data buffer inside the loop)

Comment: All i need it is just receive this text data in c#. Until now my code cant do that. Could you please see the updated code above.

Answer (score -1):

My best recommendation to you *(and I quite-consciously offer this as an “answer ...”)* is to ...

... **STOP!** ...

Your *“immediate* objective” here (and, therefore, “your immediate problem,”) is:   “to succeed in sending 23KB by means of a socket.”

At this point, you are “doing a thing that has already been done, thousands of times before.”   You are, in fact, inventing an entire *protocol.*   This is altogether unnecessary, of course, because, *no matter what* you are now doing, “it has already been done before.”   **STOP** and look for *prior art* which already knows how to solve this problem for you.   (You will have plenty of bugs of your own to solve.   Therefore, feel free to snatch already-debugged code *anywhere(!)* you can find it.)

> ***Actum Ne Agas:**   Do Not Do A Thing Already Done.™*

Comment: How does this answer the question. Douche.

Comment: How does it answer?  Easy:  by pointing out that SOMEBODY *ELSE* OUT THERE has ... not "has probably," but H-A-S ... come up with a complete and total solution, in the form of a (Java) package.  The NUMBER ONE wisdom that you will accumulate in this crazy biz is: "Do Not Do A Thing Already Done."  Therefore, instead of dumpster-diving into this "already done" morass along with the OP, in quest of yet-another one-of-a-kind 'solution' to a well-worn problem, I said:  "STOP!"

Comment: Still don't see the question answered bro. Chill out.

Comment: After 35 years in the programming business, I guess I don't have to "chlll out" when requested.  You can certainly spend an unlimited amount of time creating a "one-of-a-kind, custom-made" solution to "whatever problem first crossed the young-turk-programmer's mind," and I hope that I do not sound like too much of an old-phart when I say that I have torn-out many kilobytes of such source-code.  Until you learn to tear your mind away from "the first question that presents itself," AND "the first solution to that question that presents itself," you will waste(!) great time and money.  For nada.

Comment: Seriously:  "Here's a rabbit hole!!"  D-O-N'-T ... G-O ... I-N!!  Not until you have first satisfied yourself that you have NO alternative but to do so.  "Yes, absolutely, a socket-read has a read-limit."  But, the moment that you start to concoct YOUR OWN(!) ... ONE-OF-A-KIND(!!) ... "way to deal with that," you have just unwittingly dropped into a SNAKE hole.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not about telling people how to solve their problem, but its about helping them solve their problem.

Comment: And I most-sincerely understand and respect that principle.  Strange as it may seem, I'm trying to do precisely this.  I'm every bit as guilty as anyone else of having inadvertently re-invented a wheel because, with a too-short focus upon "the immediate next bug," I did not stop and consider it as a "build vs. steal" ;-) decision, as I long-before should have.  I jumped immediately from "what" I wanted, to "how," and to my own detriment. The C# language is rich in pre-built features and has access to a further vast library of contributed, tested, code. Most problems are already(!) well-solved.

Comment: Little example of how stealing is not always the best: Yesterday I needed a priority queue in C# so I thought yea sure that's been done. 2 hours later I had written my own unit tests for the library only to find out it wasn't using the default comparer for my objects. Could have just made it myself in that time - plus it wasn't perfect since it was an interval queue which wasn't really necessary. Not the point though. The OP gave an exact problem and you gave an opinionated answer that didn't attempt to solve the problem in the requested context.